# android webview cookies disabled error

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, instagram

I am using  android-instagram-oauth  for Instagram Login and it works fine for the first time after loggingout. when i tired to login again. am getting the cookies error . (you can see attached picture)
webview:

```
private void setUpWebView() {

        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new OAuthWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.clearFormData();
        mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false); 
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);

        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
        mContent.addView(mWebView);
    }



public  void ClearCookie()
{
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    mWebView.clearFormData();
    mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
}
```

when i tired to implement below code.and tired using different contexts.stils the same error. and fileds were filled with in webview.

https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth

[image]

Comment: What happens without `cookieManager.removeAllCookie()`? BTW `setAcceptCookie(true)` is set by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue with Google OAuth2. What worked for me was:

```
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
        CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
    }
```